# PHP script for cataloging CD

Tags: php, cd

Can someone show me a reference of script to use? For example: I have CD and I rip it and i just want to update the folder to the server. And the server will automatically fill in the song title, the song length, the album title, the artist and the release date and also it will generate 30 second length of preview

Is there a script PHP that can do this kind of thing

Thank you

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this done in PHP. I think I saw it in Perl once, and possibly Ruby as well...

Comment: SO isn't a place to go to ask people to build/show you an already built site.

Comment: I haven't seen this done in PHP...I don't believe that generating the 30 second preview in php would be efficient. What you're probably looking for is a command line tool that extracts metadata from audio-cds and then pass that data into a database, and have php read the db.

Comment: Isnt this what Windows Media Player does anyway? Why do you need a PHP script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little searching on Google for PHP MP3 Metadata comes up with this: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6026340.html
and this:
http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

as far as getting a 30 second sample, that would probably have to be done with exec() and an external program like ffmpeg.

Could feasibly have a php script as a cron job which would periodically scan an mp3 directory looking for mp3s which haven't yet been cataloged, then catalog them to the DB.

The MP3ID PEAR class used in the techrepublic article hasn't been updated in 2 years, but the getID3 was updated last month.

Comment: for the cron job, how do you do it? do you have any reference to it

Comment: Well, what sort of hosting do you have? Is it your own server or a hosting plan?  Linux or Windows?  If it's a hosting plan with someone, the control panel (like cPanel) will almost always have a Cron tool.  For Linux, if you have direct access to the server, or ssh access otherwise, you'd use crontab to set a cron job.  For Windows, you'd have to set up a scheduled task.  In any event, the command sent would be to call the php script from the command line.  Something like `/usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/script.php`

Comment: You can also use a free service like http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/ to call the script if the script is web accessible and your host doesn't support cron jobs or whatever.